# Maven Property Override in Multiple Children POM

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm working on two different products. Both have their own Parent POMs which is used by the projects to get the value for "version". We have some library projects which are used by both products. These lib project have its own version value. Actually, I have no problem in defining the dependency as the lib.version is defined in my product Parent POMs.

I'm face an issue using the Eclipse Plugin (To generate the .project, .classpath, etc files)  defined in the Parent POMs. Both products use a property to decide whether to include Version in the name of Project. Default of one product is `true` and another is `false`.

So, I decided to have version in Eclipse generated ProjectName in my lib projects and tried overriding the property used in Eclipse Plugin configuration. It works as expected when I invoke eclipse plugin from lib project. But, when I invoke from product level - after passing through the lib project, my product projects also use the overriden value and breaks the build-path in generated eclipse .classpath.

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong and suggest how to resolve this?

The problem is not with build or dependency of maven project itself, but the eclipse projects generated by plugin (.classpath).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest not using the eclipse maven plugin to generate the eclipse config files but rather use m2e to enable the maven plugin to work correctly in eclipse